# Relocate children in grid

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, xaml

I'm trying to realize a chess game in C# with WPF. By now I visualized the chess grid and the figures in it. My .xaml file contains just a grid (named "playground") which is 8x8. The initializing in the .xaml.cs file looks like the following:

```
for (int x = 0; x < 8; x++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < 8; y++)
    {
        Border border = new Border();

        if (y % 2 == (x % 2 == 0 ? 0 : 1))
        {   // Chess like look
            border.Background = black; //black is a static SolidColorBrush
        }

        // a ChessTile is an Image which can be a Figure or an EmptyTile
        // omitted code... evaluate whether what figure the tile is or empty
        ChessTile tile;

        Grid.SetColumn(border, x);
        Grid.SetRow(border, y);

        border.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
        border.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch;

        if (tile is Figure)
        {
            // Set Event to border so the user is able to click outside the image
            border.MouseDown += ClickFigure; 
        }

        border.Child = tile; // Set tile as Child
        playground.Children.Add(border); // Add border to Child
    }
}
```

After initializing I want to move a chess figure to another Column and or Row in the grid. Currently I am evaluating in ClickFigure on which empty tile the figure is able to move to, then adding a new Handler to these empty tiles and moving my Figures there. I'm calling tile.Move(otherTile) in the Handler: 
(from ChessTile.cs)

```
public Vector Coordinates
{
    get
    {
        return position; //private Vector
    }
    private set
    {
        position = value;
        Grid.SetRow(this, (int)position.X); //relocate this (ChessTile)
        Grid.SetColumn(this, (int)position.Y);
    }
}

public void Move(ChessTile other)
{
    Vector temp = position;
    Coordinates = other.position; //relocating both tiles through properties
    other.Coordinates = temp;
}
```

The problem now is that the grid does not do anything at all. I searched for some method to update/repaint the grid manually but I didn't find anything. I also tried to remove the child first and then to add it again but that gave me an error saying that the child was already bound to an `UIElement` and that I would have to seperate it first.
Do you have any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Even with, but especially without, a good [mcve], your question is far too broad. I will suggest: do _not_ create UI objects in code-behind. **Do** manage your game state strictly in two different model data structures (see e.g. "view model") representing game pieces and board locations. Game piece model will have properties for board location and selection state.

Comment: Board locations will have click command that is enabled based on e.g. first click (to select piece) and second click (to select destination), where the command's enabled state is controlled accordingly (i.e. before first click, enabled if chess piece is in that location, after first click but before second click, enabled for locations that are valid move for selected chess piece).

Comment: If the UIElement is in the grid all you have to do is change the Grid.Row / Grid.Column for that element.  I'm not sure what could be going wrong but it's just that simple.

Comment: At a minimum, you will need to research: MVVM, `ICommand`, and data templates. No doubt, that seems to you like a _lot_ more trouble than just fixing the code you have now. But I assure you, in the long run it will significantly improve the efficiency with which you write WPF code.

Comment: @PeterDuniho  I am a huge fan of MVVM and using the command interface etc. but that doesn't seem to have anything to do with moving items in a grid.

Comment: @MichaelPuckettII: of course it has something to do with moving items in a grid. The biggest reason the OP is having trouble debugging his code is that he's mixed his UI with his non-UI.

Comment: Thank you all, I'm just a student and we have to make up some project and neither have I learned something in school about MVVM or those things nor are we learning how to have a good programming style. I appreciate your help on what I have to search for and I will look that up and improve my project!

Comment: @c4ffrey  Hey man, you don't need to know MVVM to move items around in a grid.  Don't worry about what he's saying.  WPF is not an MVVM only language.  Although I personally prefer it and recommend it, it is not for beginners.  It's a design choice that's all.  There are many that you can use if you choose, and once you learn how it all works I recommend you do because they help, especially in large projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the row and column on the original `Border` placed inside the `Grid`.

In your setup code, you set column and row on a border object:

```
Grid.SetColumn(border, x);
Grid.SetRow(border, y);
```

But then in your `Coordinates` property, you're setting the column and row on `this`.

```
Grid.SetRow(this, (int)position.X); //relocate this (ChessTile)
Grid.SetColumn(this, (int)position.Y);
```

Assuming `this` is a custom class you've written, then you need to make sure it has a reference to the original `Border` and change your `Coordinate` setter to:

```
Grid.SetRow(border, (int)position.X); //relocate the border!
Grid.SetColumn(border, (int)position.Y);
```

Notice the change from `this` => `border`.